# How to correctly call useFetch function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've successfully implemented a `useFetch` function to call an API Endpoint.  It works perfectly if I add code like this to the root of a functional React component like this:

```
  const [{ data, isLoading, isError }] = useFetch(
    'http://some_api_endpoint_path'
  );
```

```
export const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsError(false);
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        setData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsError(true);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [url]);
  return [{ data, isLoading, isError }];
};
```

But let's say I want to check if a newly entered `username` exists, say upon the firing of an `onBlur` event of an input element.  When I've tried implementing this, I get this error:

```
React Hook "useFetch" is called in function "handleBlur" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

I even tried this approach:

```
  const [isChanged, setIsChanged] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    useFetch(
      'http://some_api_endpoint_path'
    );
  }, [isChanged]);
```

But got the same error.

Then I tried this simplified version, which doesn't do anything useful but I was testing the React Hooks Rules:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    useFetch(
      'http://some_api_endpoint_path'
    );
  }, []);
```

And still I got the same error.

In these last 2 cases especially, I feel that I am following the Rules of Hooks but apparently not!

What is the correct way to call `useFetch` in such a situation?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you call `useFetch` this way, right?

```
const onBlur = () => {
  const [{ data, isLoading, isError }] = useFetch(
    'http://some_api_endpoint_path'
  );
  ...
}
```

If true, this is wrong. Check this [link](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) out:

> Do not call in event handlers.

You may implement this way:

```
// Pass common initial for all fetches.
export const useFetch = (awsConfig, apiRoot, apiPathDefault) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  // Just pass the variables that changes in each new fetch requisition
  const fetchData = async (apiPath) => {
      setIsError(false);
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(apiRoot + apiPath);
        setData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsError(true);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(apiRoot + apiPathDefault);
  }, [awsConfig, apiRoot, apiPathDefault]);

  return [{ data, isLoading, isError }, fetchData];
};
```

And whenever you want to fetch again, you just call `fetchData`:

```
const [{ data, isLoading, isError }, fetchData] = useFetch(API_ROOT(), appStore.awsConfig, defaultPath);

const onBlur = () => {
  fetchData(newPath);
  ...
}
```

I've used the same principle that Apollo team used when created `useLazyQuery` (open this [link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries/) and search for `useLazyQuery`, please). Also, note that I pass all common and immutable variables when I call the hooks and pass just the mutable ones in the single fetch.

Comment: Pedro, thank you SO MUCH for your thorough and rapid response!  I can immediately see that the structure of my `useFetch` function and the way I call it is somewhat different than yours.  I'm so new to React Hooks that I don't yet understand why my approach isn't working but, regardless, I'm going to test out your approach first thing at work tomorrow!

Comment: Pedro, just wanted to thank you again!  Your code worked quite instantaneously with a standard GET Fetch.  What took longer was to get it to work with an AWS Access Token which needs to be sent.

After struggling to get it to retrieve this token from the Context API from within `useFetch`, instead for now I'm passing it as another parameter with the URL but at least it now seems to work.

Comment: @Petro Arantes
One additional question: Based on the solution you've outlined, this code pattern seems to work well from the root of a React component:
```
  const [{ data, isLoading, isError }, fetchData] = useFetch(null, null);

  const handleTestButtonClick = (event) => {
    fetchData(`${API_ROOT()}acct_mgmt/users`, appStore.awsConfig);
  };
```
Would you agree with this approach or do you have a suggested alternative?

Comment: @robertwerner-goodyear I'd implement in a different way. Check my updated answer soon

Comment: Check my answer again, please. Does it make sense?

Comment: I think I am using your approach precisely as you've outlined it.

Each call to `fetchData` makes a call to the API Endpoint.

It seems to work really well.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: One definite problem I have with declaring `const [{ data, isLoading, isError }, fetchData] = useFetch(null, null);` at the top of my component and then making assorted calls to `fetchData` is that the 2nd, 3rd, etc. still refer to the first call.  I'm not clear how to fix this.

Comment: I see. Could you edit your question as I did and add your current code, please?