# Correct way to make single conditional call to React Hooks' useFetch function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, use-effect

I have built a `useFetch` function that is closely modeled after this: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data Here's a simplified version of it: [How to correctly call useFetch function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57701733/how-to-correctly-call-usefetch-function)

Note that once the fetch is initiated, `isLoading` is set to true.

I have a use case where a fetch call needs to go out only for an admin user.  Here's the code I've added to my React component:

```
const [companies, companiesFetch] = useFetch(null, {});

if (appStore.currentAccessLevel === 99 && !companies.isLoading && newUsers.companies.length === 0) {
  console.log('About to call companiesFetch');
  companiesFetch(`${API_ROOT()}acct_mgmt/companies`);
}

useEffect(() => {
  if (!companies.isLoading && companies.status === 200) {
    newUsers.companies = companies.data.companies;
  }
}, [companies.isLoading, companies.status, newUsers.companies, companies.data]);
```

The idea with the first `if` statement is to only make the fetch call if ALL of the following is true:
 1. The currently logged in user is an admin.
 2. `companiesFetch` hasn't been previously called.
 3. `newUsers.companies` hasn't yet been populated.

This seems logical, but yet if I run this code, `companiesFetch` is called 25 times before the app crashes.  I assume the problem is a timing issue, namely that `companies.isLoading` isn't set quickly enough.

How would you fix this?

Comment: Could you share `companiesFetch` function? If there is the fetch shouldn't it be inside the `useEffect`?

Comment: @Alvaro I've modified my question to show you how I define it.  I've also included a link to another post that shows a simplified version of my actual `useFetch` function.

Comment: Why do you have to pass `\`${API_ROOT()}acct_mgmt/companies\`` to both the hook and the call to `companiesFetch()`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Sorry about that.  I've edited it how it actually is.  The first line of code simply defines an instance of `useFetch` to get the companies' data.  Then inside the `if` clause the actual fetch is made.  My question is really about why the things I'm checking for in the first `if` clause aren't sufficient to prevent entering that clause a 2nd time.  In other words, what would you check for in the first `if` to only call `companiesFetch` once?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the simplified example you've provided in the link, the problem is the `useEffect()` within the implementation of `useFetch()` that calls `fetchData()` unconditionally after the first render. Given your use-case, you don't need that behavior since you're calling it manually based on the conditions you've enumerated.

In addition to this, you've exacerbated the problem by calling `companiesFetch()` directly in the functional component, which you're not supposed to do because `fetchData()` makes synchronous calls to `setState()` and modifies your component's state during rendering.

You can solve these issues by first modifying `useFetch()` to remove the unconditional fetch after the first render, and then by moving your conditional logic into a `useEffect()` callback within the component. Here's how I'd implement `useFetch()`:

```
const initialFetchState = { isLoading: false, isError: false };

// automatically merge update objects into state
const useLegacyState = initialState => useReducer(
  (state, update) => ({ ...state, ...update }),
  initialState
);

export const useFetch = config => {
  const instance = useMemo(() => axios.create(config), [config]);
  const [state, setState] = useLegacyState(initialFetchState);
  const latestRef = useRef();
  const fetch = useCallback(async (...args) => {
    try {
      // keep ref for most recent call to fetch()
      const current = latestRef.current = Symbol();

      setState({ isError: false, isLoading: true });

      const { data } = await instance.get(...args).finally(() => {
        // cancel if fetch() was called again before this settled
        if (current !== latestRef.current) {
          return Promise.reject(new Error('cancelled by later call'));
        }
      });

      setState({ data });
    } catch (error) {
      if (current === latestRef.current) {
        setState({ isError: true });
      }
    } finally {
      if (current === latestRef.current) {
        setState({ isLoading: false });
      }
    }
  }, [instance]);

  return [state, fetch];
};
```

and here's how I'd call it within `useEffect()` to prevent synchronous calls to `setState()`:

```
const [companies, companiesFetch] = useFetch({ baseURL: API_ROOT() });
const [newUsers, setNewUsers] = useState({ companies: [] });

useEffect(() => {
  if (!companies.isLoading) {
    if (appStore.currentAccessLevel === 99 && newUsers.companies.length === 0) {
      console.log('About to call companiesFetch');
      companiesFetch('acct_mgmt/companies');
    } else if (companies.status === 200 && newUsers.companies !== companies.data.companies) {
      setNewUsers({ companies: companies.data.companies });
    }
  }
}, [appStore.currentAccessLevel, companies, newUsers]);
```

In your example, I'm not sure what scope `newUsers` was declared in, but seeing `newUsers.companies = ...` within the `useEffect()` callback raised some concern, since the implication is that your functional component is impure, which can easily lead to subtle bugs.

Comment: One immediate question: Say I wanted to use your `useFetch` for checking a UserName or Email Address or such as soon as it was entered.  How would one do that given that your `useFetch` is contained within a `useEffect`?

Also, you stated that one is not supposed to call `useFetch` directly within a functional component.  All sample code I've seen does this, for example: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data  Look at the code just above "REDUCER HOOK FOR DATA FETCHING".

Comment: @robertwerner-goodyear the example you've referenced calls `fetchData` whenever `setUrl` (aliased `doFetch`) is called with a value different from the previous call, and `doFetch()` is only called from the `onSubmit` handler, so no, it is not called during the rendering phase. As for the call triggered by the `initialUrl`, it is delayed until after the rendering phase by the `useEffect()` callback anyway, so it is still not synchronous.

Comment: @robertwerner-goodyear by the way, I'm not a big fan of the example code provided in that blog post. The asynchronous calls to `setState()` within the custom hooks there cause race conditions for the component state whenever there's concurrent axios requests pending.

Comment: Yes, understood.  Hey, I tried to reach out to you privately.  Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: @robertwerner-goodyear "Tried to"? I prefer not to accept private communication from Stack Overflow, but you can message me [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199979/room-for-patrick-roberts-and-robertwerner-goodyear) if you want.